# Difference between simple past and past progressive

Tags: difference, past-tense, past-continuous

When you remember about an event and refer it, would you use simple past or past progressive?

For example:

Yesterday I went to a rock concert.  I liked the last song very much.  *Everyone was singing it*. I was impressed.

Or can I say like this using simple past:

Yesterday I went to a rock concert.  I liked the last song very much.  *Everyone sang it*.  I was impressed.

I don't really understand the nuance of these two expressions.

Can I say both?  If so, what is their difference?

And I have another question:
How would it be if I add the verb "enjoy" to it?

> Everyone was enjoying singing it.
>
> Everyone enjoyed singing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Past progressive can be a richer, more descriptive use of language. It can help put more focus on the timing of the event and enable the reader/listener to picture the scene.

For example, "*I went to a concert. The band played well. Everybody sang*" is just a list of things that happened. It sounds a little bland.

By contrast, "*Last night I went to a concert. Everybody was singing while the band was playing*" is more colourful. It better conveys that the singing was going on throughout the concert, rather than just a fixed event that happened at some point during it. The reader/listener might be able to picture themselves there, with everybody around them, singing.